# How to shuffle a deck of struct cards without using an array in c

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, typedef

I have this code. I create 10 cards in function `createDeck` and i want to shuffle the cards in function `MyDeckOutput` without using an array. Can someone help??

I have no idea and my teacher wants like that. I am not allow to use c++ or something extern. :/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>

typedef struct Card
{
    char name[50];
    int maxAlter;
    float maxGewicht;
    double maxLaenge;
    struct Card* pNext;
} cards;

cards* createDeck()
{
    cards* pStart = NULL;
    cards* pLast = NULL;
    cards* pNew = (cards*)malloc(sizeof(cards));
    for (int iElm = 0; iElm < 10; iElm++) {
        cards* pNew = (cards*)malloc(sizeof(cards));
        if (iElm == 0) { strcpy_s(pNew->name, "Ameisenbaer"); pNew->maxAlter = 14; pNew->maxGewicht = 39; pNew->maxLaenge = 0.90; pNew->pNext = NULL; }
        if (iElm == 1) { strcpy_s(pNew->name, "Biber"); pNew->maxAlter = 21; pNew->maxGewicht = 30; pNew->maxLaenge = 1.02; pNew->pNext = NULL; }
        if (iElm == 2) { strcpy_s(pNew->name, "Brauenbaer"); pNew->maxAlter = 30; pNew->maxGewicht = 600; pNew->maxLaenge = 1.50; pNew->pNext = NULL; }
        if (iElm == 3) { strcpy_s(pNew->name, "Delfin"); pNew->maxAlter = 45; pNew->maxGewicht = 150; pNew->maxLaenge = 7.00; pNew->pNext = NULL; }
        if (iElm == 4) { strcpy_s(pNew->name, "Elefant"); pNew->maxAlter = 70; pNew->maxGewicht = 6000; pNew->maxLaenge = 3.00; pNew->pNext = NULL; }
        if (iElm == 5) { strcpy_s(pNew->name, "Esel"); pNew->maxAlter = 14; pNew->maxGewicht = 39; pNew->maxLaenge = 0.90; pNew->pNext = NULL; }
        if (iElm == 6) { strcpy_s(pNew->name, "Federmaus"); pNew->maxAlter = 21; pNew->maxGewicht = 30; pNew->maxLaenge = 1.02; pNew->pNext = NULL; }
        if (iElm == 7) { strcpy_s(pNew->name, "Fuchs"); pNew->maxAlter = 30; pNew->maxGewicht = 600; pNew->maxLaenge = 1.50; pNew->pNext = NULL; }
        if (iElm == 8) { strcpy_s(pNew->name, "Gorilla"); pNew->maxAlter = 45; pNew->maxGewicht = 150; pNew->maxLaenge = 7.00; pNew->pNext = NULL; }
        if (iElm == 9) { strcpy_s(pNew->name, "Giraffe"); pNew->maxAlter = 70; pNew->maxGewicht = 6000; pNew->maxLaenge = 3.20; pNew->pNext = NULL; }
        pNew->pNext = NULL;
        if (pStart == NULL) pStart = pNew;
        if (pLast != NULL) pLast->pNext = pNew;
        pLast = pNew;
    }
    return pStart;
}

/*void MyDeckOutput(cards* pStart)
{
    int iEle = 0;
    for (cards* pOut = pStart; pOut != NULL; pOut = pOut->pNext)
    {
        iEle++;
        if (iEle < 6) printf("name = %s\n", pOut->name);
    }
}*/

void MyDeckOutput(cards* pStart)
{
    for (cards* pOut = pStart; pOut != NULL; pOut = pOut->pNext) printf("name = %s\n", pOut->name);
}

void shuffleDeck(cards* pStart)
{
    cards* shuffled = NULL;
    cards* end = NULL;
    int numberOfCards = 10; // cards number
    srand(time(NULL)); // seeds the random nr generator with the current
    while (numberOfCards > 0)
    {
        int index = rand() % numberOfCards;
        cards* previousCard = NULL;
        cards* selectedCard = pStart->pNext;
        // iterate over linked list
        if (!shuffled)
            end = shuffled = selectedCard;
        else
            end->pNext = selectedCard;

        if (previousCard)
            previousCard->pNext = selectedCard->pNext;
        end->pNext = NULL;
        --numberOfCards;

        printf("name = %s%i\n", selectedCard->name, index);
    }
}

int main()
{
    cards* pStart = createDeck();
    MyDeckOutput(pStart);
    printf("\n\nShuffel:\n");
    shuffleDeck(pStart);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Your teacher wants you to learn about linked lists. Pick a random card. Remove it from the original linked list. Add it to the shuffled linked list. Repeat until the original linked list is empty. In `main` you should have `cards* pShuffled = shuffleDeck(pStart);`

Comment: You are missing `{ }` after each `if` inside the loop, thus the `if` will only affect the `strcpy_s` and not the rest of each line. (You seem to be using similar syntax with the `for` loop in `MyDeckOutput` later – it only works because there is only one statement in the loop body. Please use `{}` and indentation rather than this.)

Comment: The comment 'iterate over linked list' was not supposed to mean 'that's what this line does', but much rather was supposed to be a prompt for you to insert just that at this location. Y'know, to support the learning process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commentor @user3386109 is spot on with his suggestion.

To help you get started, here's a little code snippet to do what you need to do.

```
void shuffleDeck(cards *deck)
{
    cards *shuffled = NULL;
    cards *end = NULL;
    int numberOfCards = countDeck(deck); //Count number of cards in your deck
    srand(time(NULL));  //Seeds the random number generator with the current 
    while (numberOfCards > 0)
    {
        int index = rand()%numberOfCards;
        cards *previousCard = NULL;
        cards *selectedCard;
        //Iterate over linked list until you arrive at index 'x'.
        if (!shuffled)
            end = shuffled = selectedCard;
        else
            end->next = selectedCard;

        if (previousCard)
            previousCard->next = selectedCard->next;
        end->next = NULL;
        --numberOfCards;
    }
}
```

Please note that this code is incomplete on purpose and merely meant to give you an idea on how to do it.

Edit: I'm not really supposed to do this, but this shuffle code works for me.

```
cards *shuffleDeck(cards *deck)
{
    cards *shuffled = NULL;
    cards *end = NULL;
    int numberOfCards = countDeck(deck); //Count number of cards in your deck
    srand(time(NULL));  //Seeds the random number generator with the current
    while (numberOfCards > 0)
    {
        int index = rand()%numberOfCards;
        cards *previousCard = NULL;
        cards *selectedCard = deck;
    
        //Iterate over linked list until you arrive at index 'x'.
        for (int i = 0; i < index && selectedCard; ++i)
        {
            previousCard = selectedCard;
            selectedCard = selectedCard->pNext;
        }
    
        if (!shuffled)
            shuffled = selectedCard;
        else if (end)
            end->pNext = selectedCard;
        end = selectedCard;
    
        if (selectedCard)
        {
            if (previousCard)
                previousCard->pNext = selectedCard->pNext;  //Closes the gap between the previous element and the next element.
            else
                deck = selectedCard->pNext;                 //Resets the anchor element.
            selectedCard->pNext = NULL;
        }
        --numberOfCards;
    }
    
    return shuffled;
}

int main()
{
    MyDeckOutput(shuffleDeck(createDeck()));
    return 0;
};
```

I will leave filling the gaps to you (how to count the number of the cards).

Please also note, that your 'creating a card' is faulty.
Either use curly braces (`{}`) around your assignments or, better yet, use a dedicated function.

Alternatively I recommend reading about 'switch/case' statements.

Comment: how can i put my deck in the parameter 'deck' 

Comment: You simply pass it the pointer you obtained when you called `createDeck`. Function parameters do not need to share the names of the variables they are passed.

Comment: I dont understand it after 3 hours of playing around and try everything  I understand only seperate points. I cant bring it to output the shuffled deck. Can you help me? 

Comment: The problem is: we havent learn how to do that and i am a web developer and not a c developer 

Comment: There are a number of problems in your code, actually.
One of them is the missing braces in your createDeck function. The only thing that happens on `iElm == x` is the strcpy. All the others will be executed unconditionally, meaning that at the end of the day, all cards will be 70 years old, weigh 6000 kg and be 3.2 meters long. That said, I must ask: Is this an assignment for your company or are you actually trying to learn C?

Comment: @GhiathSardast I added some more details to my solution. Now I've done about 80 % of your work for you. I trust you'll be able to handle the remaining 20?

Comment: 1. I have updated my Code.

Comment: I have noticed and responded.

Comment: 2. I am in switzerland in the professional school and there when you want to learn a job (programming) you must learn a lot of things that you dont need. In my company i dont need c and i wont too learn it but in the school i must.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help. :)

Comment: @GhiathSardast Bitte schön. Ich freu' mich immer, wenn ich helfen kann. Schöne Grüße aus Deutschland.

Comment: @GhiathSardast Ah yes, if you consider your problem solved, please click the 'Accept' (The green checkmark) button next to the answer that you think helped you best. This way, other people from SO will know that you don't need any more help on this issue.

Comment: Ich bin jetzt sehr weit gekommen aber ich bin auf ein Problem gestossen  Ich habe eine letzte Frage glaube ich  und zwar wie kann ich die ersten 5 Karten in eine Variable speicher z.B. myCards und die anderen 5 Karten in eine andere z.B. opCards. So dass ich meine Karten separat ausgeben kann.

Comment: And the green checkmark is save for you 

Comment: If you want to maintain your linked list structure (as the assignment states), the easiest way is to iterate to the 'cutting point' (as illustrated in the code snippet), transfer `currentCard->next` to the variable `opCards` and set `next` to `NULL` afterwards. Congratulations, you've just severed the linked list. Also, please do not forget to `free` the cards once you are done with them.